# Why am I getting an missing ')' identifier error in the following code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that counts the number of perfect numbers within a limit, but the compiler keeps on giving me the "missing ')' before identifier 'num_squares'" error. Please help...

```
int main(void) {
 int num_squares = 0;
 int limit = 30;
 while(num_squares * num_squares < limit)
  num_squares++;

 printf("%d," num_squares);

}
```

Comment: ah, printf calling convention ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know about that part of the code, but you're missing a comma in your printf

```
printf("%d," num_squares);
```

should be

```
printf("%d,", num_squares);
```

Answer (score 3):

You put comma inside ""-quotes in printf("%d," .

also please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

use , after double qoutes in printf

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
printf("%d," num_squares);
```

Should be:

```
printf("%d", num_squares);
```